# Rivet gun not gripping rivet again on 2nd pull?

Tags: tools, hand-tools, rivets, pop-rivets

I'm using a (brand-new) hand rivet gun to re-attach 2 plastic pieces of a car bumper (there were rivets here previously).

The first rivet went in perfectly. But since then the rivet gun seems to push the rivet out whenever I attempt a 2nd pull(pump?). Because the rivet now moves with the gun I cannot complete the job. I have to pull the rivet out part done.

Would anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you pushing the gun down over the rivet?  Did you check that the gun is clean and does not have something in it?

Comment: Does the 'shaft' of the rivet move up and down inside the 'body', preventing the rivet gun from moving to pull on the next section of the shaft?

Comment: You probably have a stuck pin inside the gun...from the first rivet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the pop rivet is gripped with the teeth on the inside the first time, there is nothing to keep the rivet on the inside while the teeth are supposed to "regrip" the pop rivet. You need to keep the pop rivet in the gun from coming back out while releasing the handle so the grippers on the inside can get a new "bite". When the pop rivet is in its drilled hole this is hard to keep track of, I have had the shaft simply move in and out, never releasing from the teeth on the inside to get a new grip. The only way I have been able to get past that is remove the gun, make sure the shaft is all the way out, CAREFULLY reset the gun over the pin, and hopefully it will pull the shaft far enough into the rivet to keep it from going back out again.

Comment: Yes I found I could make it work by pushing the gun against the rivet when I released the grips. It was like the teeth were still gripping on release and pushing the rivet in the opposite direction.